# First responder problems

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nswindow, first-responder

My application is a menu-bar app. It has a panel which holds another view. 
This view changes, and I each one of those should do it's own key-handling.
When I change the first responder, only the current first responder get's the key-down notification, obviously.

But there should also be a global key-handling for the panel itself.

How am I supposed to do this?
Multiple implementation is very ugly :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out. 
I guess the superclass is calling the event-methods of the superview. 
Then the superview is notifying it's superview. And so on.
If you call `[super keyDown:theEvent];` it's done for you.

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
     [super keyDown:theEvent];

     // Do you your stuff here 
}
```